# iterating over a dictionary of lists with ansible loop

Tags: ansible

I have the following test playbook to loop over a dictionary of lists.

```
- hosts: localhost

  connection: local

  vars:

    machine_roles:

      masters: ["master1","master2"]
      workers: ["worker1","worker2"]

  tasks:

    - name: toto
      debug:
       msg: "{{ item.0.role}} --- {{ item.1 }}"

      loop:
        - "{{ machine_roles | dict2items(key_name='role', value_name='machine') | subelements('machine') }}"
```

I would like to get as output the following:

```
masters --- master1
masters --- master2
workers --- worker1
workers --- worker2
```

Based on my understanding of the documentation and similar posts I would expect my playbook to do the job. However, when running it I get the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'role'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/git/visa-jupyter/jupyterhub-kubespawner/test.yml': line 14, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: toto\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Surprisingly when debugging the results of `{{ machine_roles | dict2items(key_name='role', value_name='machine') | subelements('machine') }}`, I get:

```
    [
        [
            {
                "machine": [
                    "master1", 
                    "master2"
                ], 
                "role": "masters"
            }, 
            "master1"
        ], 
        [
            {
                "machine": [
                    "master1", 
                    "master2"
                ], 
                "role": "masters"
            }, 
            "master2"
        ], 
        [
            {
                "machine": [
                    "worker1", 
                    "worker2"
                ], 
                "role": "workers"
            }, 
            "worker1"
        ], 
        [
            {
                "machine": [
                    "worker1", 
                    "worker2"
                ], 
                "role": "workers"
            }, 
            "worker2"
        ]
    ]
```

This looks to me the expected result as explained in the documentation when combining `dict2items` and `subelements`.

Why applying the `loop` command upon this data structure fails or at least does not produce what I would expect ?

[EDIT & ANSWER]
I could finally find the error. I was myself blowing my foot by introducing another loop level by doing:

```
loop:
  - "{{ machine_roles | dict2items(key_name='role', value_name='machine') | subelements('machine') }}"
```

The correct syntax being (for my purpose):

```
loop: "{{ machine_roles | dict2items(key_name='role', value_name='machine') | subelements('machine') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be some strange formatting/indentation problem. Your code works fine

```
"msg": "masters --- master1"
"msg": "masters --- master2"
"msg": "workers --- worker1"
"msg": "workers --- worker2"
```

FWIW. Here is the link to the tested [code](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/blob/master/examples/example-040/subelement-loop-13.yml).

Comment: I could finally found my mistake. Cf my edit for info. Comparing with your version showed me the way. Thanks.